# SQL Counting (More than)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
distrikt = district

SELECT POST.distrikt, COUNT(PERSON.personnr)
  FROM [dbo].POST join [dbo].PERSON on POST.postnr = PERSON.postnr
  WHERE ?
  GROUP BY POST.distrikt
GO
```

I need to view the districts showing the number of persons associated with each, but it should only show the districts which contain 2 or more persons. I tried using `COUNT(PERSON.personnr) > 2`, but that didn't work. Apart from that, it shows the districts and associated persons just fine.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to filter based on the results of `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT POST.distrikt, COUNT(PERSON.personnr)
FROM [dbo].POST join [dbo].PERSON on POST.postnr = PERSON.postnr
GROUP BY POST.distrikt
HAVING COUNT(PERSON.personnr) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `having` clause:

```
SELECT POST.distrikt, COUNT(PERSON.personnr)
  FROM [dbo].POST join [dbo].PERSON on POST.postnr = PERSON.postnr
  GROUP BY POST.distrikt
  HAVING count(PERSON.personnr) > 2
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html for example. Search for `having`.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
HAVING COUNT(PERSON.personnr) > 2
```

after your group by